# My methods are running twice when they should only run once and map.get() is affecting all entries

Tags: java, maps

So, I'm working on a project with a loop (`while (true) { //do stuff`) and I have values stored in a map (only 2 entries).

First issue: Methods are executing twice (I think it is an issue in the map portion). The VirtualPet.tick and the VirtualPet.feed method is being executed twice per loop.

Second issue: map.get(key) is executing on all keys, not just specified key.

In my main class:

```
    private static VirtualPetShelter shelter = new VirtualPetShelter();
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generatePets();
        gameLoop();
    }

    private static void showPets() {
        shelter.showPets();
    }

    private static void generatePets() {
        VirtualPet pet1 = new VirtualPet();
        VirtualPet pet2 = new VirtualPet();
        shelter.addPet("Max", pet1);
        shelter.addPet("Skippy", pet1);
    }

    private static void gameLoop() {
        while (true) {

            whatToDo();
            shelter.tick();
            showPets();
        }
    }

    private static void whatToDo() {
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("\t 1: Feed");

        int response = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        switch (response) {
            case 1:
                feedOptions();
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void feedOptions() {
        System.out.println("Enter pet name or \"all\" to feed all:");
        showPetNames();
        String response = input.nextLine();

        if (response.toLowerCase().equals("all")) {
            shelter.feedAllPets();
        } else {
            shelter.feedPet(response);
        }
    }
```

In my Shelter class:

```
private Map<String, VirtualPet> pets = new HashMap<>();

    public VirtualPetShelter() {
    }

    public void addPet(String name, VirtualPet pet) {
        pets.put(name, pet);
    }

    public void showPets() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, VirtualPet> entry : pets.entrySet())
            System.out.println("\t" + entry.getKey() + "\n" +
                    "\t\tHunger: " + entry.getValue().getHunger());
    }

    public void showPetNames() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, VirtualPet> entry : pets.entrySet())
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }

    public void feedAllPets() {
        for (VirtualPet value : pets.values())
            value.feed();
    }

    public void feedPet(String name) {
        pets.get(name).feed();
    }

    public void tick() {
        for (VirtualPet value : pets.values())
            value.tick();
    }
```

In VirtualPet class:

```
    private int hunger;

    public VirtualPet() {
        hunger = 5;
    }

    public int getHunger() {
        return hunger;
    }

    public void feed() {
        hunger -= 2;
    }

    public void tick(){
       hunger += 1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide code of `VirtualPet::feed()` method?  Do you have hierarchy of pets and call `super.feed()` method in children classes?

Comment: I'll add the edit. I don't know what that is, so probably not. I am new to Java.

Comment: We haven't learned about that yet. I only have 3 classes the main class (pet app), the shelter class, and the virtual pet class.

Comment: It seems you need to enhance your question and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That's basically everything (in edit). I didn't have any issues until I switched from arraylist to a map instead, and now it's just not working for me.

Comment: well the pets map is actually empty, where do you fill it up?

Comment: Sorry, I left that part out. Here it is. I'll add to the post: (I was trying to minimize)

```
private static void generatePets() {
        VirtualPet pet1 = new VirtualPet();
        VirtualPet pet2 = new VirtualPet();
        shelter.addPet("Max", pet1);
        shelter.addPet("Skippy", pet1);
    }
```

Comment: So you're adding the same pet twice.  It should be: `shelter.addPet("Max", pet1); shelter.addPet("Skippy", pet2);`

Comment: You are adding pet1 twice

Comment: Good Catch! I just changed it, I'm checking it out now.

Comment: Everything is perfect now. OMG I can't believe i spent an hour and a half trying to figure this out :/ I wrote the entire program in 40 mins then spent over twice as long trying to figure out the issue Thank you both